# I feel like the input code I put into my struct can be condensed, any suggestions on how to keep the data individual while keeping the code short?

Tags: c++, struct

I've been trying to figure out how to input information into my struct, but I would like to condense the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Employee //The whole program is going to revolve around this struct
{
    char first[10], last[10];
    float Hours_Worked, Hourly_Rate, Fed_Tax_Rate, St_Tax_Rate;
}Kobe, Lebron, Larry, Michael; //Struct declarations
```

The Code right here is the one I'm talking about. My preferred design was to use a for loop that loops 4 times, however I need individual information.

```
int main()
{
    Employee Kobe;
    cout << "First name: ";
    cin >> Kobe.first;
    cout << "Last name: ";
    cin >> Kobe.last;
    cout << "Hours worked: ";
    cin >> Kobe.Hours_Worked;
    cout << "Federal Tax Rate: ";
    cin >> Kobe.Fed_Tax_Rate;
    cout << "State Tax Rate: ";
    cin >> Kobe.St_Tax_Rate;

    Employee Lebron;
    cout << "First name: ";
    cin >> Lebron.first;
    cout << "Last name: ";
    cin >> Lebron.last;
    cout << "Hours worked: ";
    cin >> Lebron.Hours_Worked;
    cout << "Federal Tax Rate: ";
    cin >> Lebron.Fed_Tax_Rate;
    cout << "State Tax Rate: ";
    cin >> Lebron.St_Tax_Rate;

    Employee Larry;
    cout << "First name: ";
    cin >> Larry.first;
    cout << "Last name: ";
    cin >> Larry.last;
    cout << "Hours worked: ";
    cin >> Larry.Hours_Worked;
    cout << "Federal Tax Rate: ";
    cin >> Larry.Fed_Tax_Rate;
    cout << "State Tax Rate: ";
    cin >> Larry.St_Tax_Rate;

    Employee Michael;
    cout << "First name: ";
    cin >> Michael.first;
    cout << "Last name: ";
    cin >> Michael.last;
    cout << "Hours worked: ";
    cin >> Michael.Hours_Worked;
    cout << "Federal Tax Rate: ";
    cin >> Michael.Fed_Tax_Rate;
    cout << "State Tax Rate: ";
    cin >> Michael.St_Tax_Rate;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any problem can be solved by adding another level of indirection.

Comment: Make a `read` method for `Employee` and put all of the reading code into it. Then you can `Kobe.read(cin); Michael.read(cin);` etc...

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but we have not gone over the read method in my class yet, therefore I cant use it at the moment. Thanks though!

Comment: The `read` method is not something you go over in class. It is something you write yourself.

Comment: What I mean is that, we haven't learned it yet so we need to use other methods. I'm trying to see if there are other methods I could use, i.e. a function that can cycle through the 4 employees.

Comment: @Swordfish had a perfect viable alternative. I'm not sure why they deleted it seconds before I could upvote.

Comment: @user4581301 I deleted it cause in the question it reads "The Code right here is the one I'm talking about. My preferred design was to use a for loop that loops 4 times, however I need individual information." that together with the OPs comment on your answer brought me to the conclusion that he wants four seperate variables instead of an array, for whatever reason there might be (none? ;).

Comment: @Swordfish, no an array would work, but we would have to combine it with a struct no? You should repost your syntax, I can probably get something out of it.

Comment: I see it as worth keeping around because odds are really good that in the near future the Asker may realize that large numbers of individually-named variables is for suckers. For example, what if the details for Michael are entered for `Kobe`? Should this matter, other than causing potential confusion.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I just rewrote the syntax with an array since my mind is being refreshed on these concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a `Employee` with an input method to get the input

```
struct Employee 
{
    char first[10], last[10];
    float Hours_Worked, Hourly_Rate, Fed_Tax_Rate, St_Tax_Rate;

    bool getinput(std::istream & in, 
                  std::ostream & out);
};
```

Then you implement this method

```
bool Employee::getinput(std::istream & in, 
                        std::ostream & out);
{
    out << "First name: ";
    in >> first;
    out << "Last name: ";
    in >> last;
    out << "Hours worked: ";
    in >> Hours_Worked;
    out << "Federal Tax Rate: ";
    in >> Fed_Tax_Rate;
    out << "State Tax Rate: ";
    in >> St_Tax_Rate;

    return in.good(); //always good to know if the input succeeded

}
```

and then you call the method

```
Employee Kobe;
Kobe.getinput(cin, cout);
Employee Lebron;
Lebron.getinput(cin, cout);
Employee Larry;
Larry.getinput(cin, cout);
Employee Michael;
Michael.getinput(cin, cout);
```

`cin` and `cout` are being passed in in an abstracted form so that you can call `getinput` on different input streams, a network socket for example.

Comment: Perfect, thats the exact explanation I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array of `Employee`s and a `for`-loop to avoid writing duplicate code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Employee
{
    char first[10];
    char last[10];
    float Hours_Worked;
    float Hourly_Rate;
    float Fed_Tax_Rate;
    float St_Tax_Rate;
};

int main()
{
    Employee employees[4];

    for (auto &e : employees) {
        cout << "First name: ";
        cin >> e.first;
        cout << "Last name: ";
        cin >> e.last;
        cout << "Hours worked: ";
        cin >> e.Hours_Worked;
        cout << "Hourly rate: ";
        cin >> e.Hourly_Rate;
        cout << "Federal Tax Rate: ";
        cin >> e.Fed_Tax_Rate;
        cout << "State Tax Rate: ";
        cin >> e.St_Tax_Rate;
    }

    for (auto const &e : employees)
        cout << e.first << ' ' << e.last << '\n' << e.Hours_Worked << " / "
             << e.Hourly_Rate << " / " << e.Fed_Tax_Rate << " / " << e.St_Tax_Rate << "\n\n";
}
```

If you're not (yet) familiar with range-based `for`-loops you can of course use traditional loops like

```
for(size_t i{}; i < sizeof(employees)/sizeof(*employees); ++i)
    // and access eployees[i] in the loops body.
```